# How to remove the duplicated part of string by comparing two string in Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$str1='<option value="AAA">AAA</option><option value="BBB">BBB</option><option value="CCC">CCC</option>';

$str2='<option value="CCC">CCC</option><option value="DDD">DDD</option>';
```

I would like the expected result as following. If some part of `$str2` which is duplicated with part of `$str1`, then removing the duplicated part of $str2.

Expected result:

```
$expectedStr = '<option value="DDD">DDD</option>';
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str1='<option value="AAA">AAA</option><option value="BBB">BBB</option><option value="CCC">CCC</option>',
    str2='<option value="CCC">CCC</option><option value="DDD">DDD</option>',

    result = str2.replace(/<option .+?<\/option>/g, function(m) {
        return (str1.indexOf(m) > -1)? "" : m;
    });

console.log(result); //returns <option value="DDD">DDD</option>
```

(here I'm supposing you want to check for "atomic" substring `<option>...</option>`)

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jAyAE/